# CALayer can't be seen

Tags: swift, macos, calayer

I'm trying to learn swift. So far, my code runs, but it doesn't show a CAlayer I create:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

var window: NSWindow!
var mainview: NSView!
var redLayer: CATextLayer!


func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

    self.mainview = NSView(frame: NSRect(x:0,y:0,width:300,height:300))


    self.window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 300, 300),
        styleMask: NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask |
        NSMiniaturizableWindowMask,
        backing: .Buffered, `defer`: false)

    self.window.contentView!.addSubview(self.mainview)
    self.window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self.window)
    self.window.makeMainWindow()
    self.redLayer = CATextLayer()
    self.redLayer.string = "test"
    self.redLayer.frame = self.mainview.bounds
    self.redLayer.bounds = CGRect(x:50,y:50,width:300,height:300)
    self.redLayer.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)
    self.redLayer.backgroundColor = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    self.redLayer.foregroundColor = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    self.redLayer.hidden = false
    self.mainview.layer = self.redLayer
}

func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}}
```

the code gives a gray empty window. but I want it to show a colored window with a line of text saying "test", but I can't see these stuff.

I tried multiple ways, I can't fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OS X, Core Animation support (`CALayer`) is not enabled automatically. You have to [manually enable it](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/SettingUpLayerObjects/SettingUpLayerObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH13-SW5). For a programmatically created view, use the `wantsLayer` property.

```
self.mainview.wantsLayer = true
```

Comment: Indeed, this fixed the problem!